# Oracle trigger before update

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm new to Oracle sql syntax. I want to change `order_status_code` of `Orders`, when `Invoice`'s `invoice_status_code` was set to 1. However, when I change `invoice_status_code`, it prints error, which says `Cannot update Orders because Shipment exists.`

```
create or replace TRIGGER change_order_status
before update of invoice_status_code on Invoice
for each row
begin 
   if :new.invoice_status_code = 1 then 
      update Orders 
      set order_status_code = 1
      where order_id = :new.order_id;
    end if;
end;
```

This is how I update

```
update invoice 
set invoice_status_code = 1
where invoice_number = 2
```

Error message:

```
Error starting at line : 2 in command -
update invoice 
set invoice_status_code = 1
where invoice_number = 2
Error report -
ORA-20005: Cannot update Orders because Shipment exists.
```

[image: ER diagram]

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message printed?

Comment: @KaushikNayak If there wouldn't be any errors, I'd not have created this question here.

Comment: @Kas . . . Does it work if you set this up as an `after update` trigger?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no:(

Comment: Not saying that your question isn't a genuine onebut that doesn't look like an Oracle 's error message

Comment: @KaushikNayak I've updated this post. I guess it might help to identify the problem

Comment: You have other checks or triggers that is preventing this from happening.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you, Indeed, there were some triggers which were active. I've disabled them, but a new error appeared. ORA-02292: integrity constraint (..) violated - child record found”

Comment: @Kas . . . You are going to have to accept that you cannot do what you want to do.  It seems to violate the data integrity rules that have been set up in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the second error in your comment, my guess is that there is a foreign key in `shipment` that references the `(order_id, order_status_code)` in `orders`. Since you have a row in `shipment` using that to refer to a row in `orders`, you cannot change the column in `orders`.

It seems odd that you have `order_status_code` in `orders`, `shipment`, and `invoice`. Assuming that is referring to the status of a single row in `orders`, I'd expect it to be in that table and no others.

*P.S. User defined error codes are between `ORA-20000` and `ORA-20999`. The first error stays in this range.*